# How to check for network total traffic in Windows Azure (Virtual Machine)

Tags: networking, azure, virtual-machine

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine running on Windows Azure. I need to check how much data has been uploaded/downloaded.

I can check for current values in the windows azure dashboard, but I can't find anything about totals.

If there is no such information available, is there a way I can set up a counter for that on Ubuntu that keeps track of network totals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like zabbix or nagios

Comment: I was looking for something simpler but these tools might actualy come in handy for a more complete monitoring! So thank you!